# Displaying both sides of a ManyToMany relationship in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, manytomanyfield

Say I have the following models that have a many-to-many relationship:

## models.py:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    foos = models.ManyToManyField(Foo, related_name='bars')
```

And then having defined them in admin in the following way:

## admin.py

```
@admin.register(Foo)
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

@admin.register(Bar)
class BarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

In Django admin, when browsing `Bar` instances, I can see the `Foo` instances `Bar` is associated with and can modify them from there.

However, no such luck with `Foo`, I can't see the `Bar` instances that every Foo object is associated with.

Can Django define automatic handling for this or would I need to roll my own methond?

I'm using Python 3.6.1 and Django 1.11.

Comment: In your `ManyToManyField` you're referencing `A`. Is that right? I'd expect: `ManyToManyField(Foo, related_name='bars')`.

Comment: @cezar, yes, sorry `A` was supposed to be `Foo`, will correct

Comment: linking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61566930/6359659) here. They are related and solved my problem as a couple.

Answer (score 25):

You could define a custom `InlineModelAdmin` like so:

```
class BarInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Bar.foos.through
```

and use it in your `FooAdmin`:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
"""Foo admin."""
    model = Foo
    inlines = [
        BarInline,
    ]
```

Have a look at this part of the django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models).

Comment: This is the cleanest solution.

Comment: @Hopiu any idea to make bar field Autofill?

Comment: For autocomplete use **autocomplete_fields = ['some_field']** inside class **BarInline**

Answer (score 4):

You can define custom fields for `list_display` like this:

```
@admin.register(Foo)
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Foo admin."""

    list_display = ('name', 'get_bars')
    search_fields = ('name',)

    def get_bars(self, obj):
        return obj.bars.all()
```

This is a very simple example, but I hope it can help you as a starting point.

EDIT:

You can display the associated objects in the edit form as readonly:

```
readonly_fields = ('get_bars',)
fields = ('name', 'get_bars')
```

Comment: Thank you, is this just for listing? Would I need to roll my own logic to support editing? Sorry, not very familiar with Django.

Comment: Yes, this particular example is for listing. Now I realize, you need something for the edit form, i.e. `fields`.

Comment: I think that'll do for now, I'll add that and be on the lookout for a way to support editing. Just one question, why doesn't Django provide a bi-directional support for editing? I'm not familiar with what happens under the hood.

Comment: According to the documentation, the `fields` i.e. the admin form can display editable fields only for the fields defined on the model. In your case `foos` is defined on `Bar` and will be displayed in its admin form, but `bars` is a related name and not defined as a field on `Foo`, thus not displaying in Foo's admin form. I don't know the exact mechanism behind.

Answer (score 1):

This code below can display both `Foo` and `Bar` models in **many-to-many relationship** on the same page in Django Admin:

```py
class BarInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Bar.foos.through

@admin.register(Foo)
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (BarInline,)
```

Be careful, if using `model = Bar` instead of `model = Bar.foos.through` in **many-to-many relationship** as shown below:

```py
class BarInline(admin.TabularInline):
    # model = Bar.foos.through
    model = Bar # This will get error

@admin.register(Foo)
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (BarInline,)
```

You will get the error below:

> ERRORS: <class 'xxx.admin.BarInline'>: (admin.E202)
> 'xxx.Bar' has no ForeignKey to 'xxx.Foo'.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called [django-admin-extend](https://github.com/kux/django-admin-extend) which provides a generic mechanism to define "Bidirectional many to many fields". I'm not sure if it still works, because the last contribution is two years old, bit it should be worth giving it a try.