# How to join tables with ManyToManyField type in Django?

Tags: python, django, inner-join, relation, manytomanyfield

I have models like this:

```
class Education(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(default=None)
    price = models.ManyToManyField(Price)

class Price(models.Model):
    cost = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=20)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

And i want to inner join between two tables and access to all fields of both.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61566808/manytomany-relationship-between-two-models-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve like this,

`Education.objects.filter(price__in=Price.objects.all()).select_related('Price').values_list('title', 'content', 'price__cost', 'price__created_at')`

Comment: how i can group by based on Education.id with latest cost parameter that inserted. It means i addition to get list of grouped educations, i wanna get the latest cost that inserted for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70004553/3319132