# How to inner join tables based on ManyToManyField and group by a parameter and get latest one in Django?

Tags: django, join, group-by, inner-join, relation

I have two models with ManyToManyField relationship:

```
class Education(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(default=None)
    price = models.ManyToManyField(Price)

class Price(models.Model):
    cost = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=20)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

I can fetch all rows like this:

```
result = Education.objects.filter(price__in=Price.objects.all()).select_related('Price')/
.values_list('title', 'content', 'price__cost', 'price__created_at')
```

But now i want to **group by** `education.id` and the `cost` parameter should be latest parameter that inserted(based on `created_at`).

So i want to have list of all `Education` with latest `cost` that inserted for every education.

Answer (score 0):

Will it work for you, It will return the respective id

`Education.objects.filter(price__in=Price.objects.all()).select_related('Price').values('id').annotate(price_id=Max('price__id'))`